# Manipulate problem with long expression (wrong function definition?)

Tags: functions, manipulate

I have got a long expression called h, which I don't think is relevant to define here for the issue I have. Just know that it was defined through symbols, like

```
 h=C1*Sin[...]*Integrate[...] etc.
```

So my definition has no [x_] or :=
It seems to work well until here (I get the long expression for h in terms of the symbols)
Then, what I would like to do is defining a function with all the undefined parameters that appear in h, that is, in my case:

```
h1[x_,alpha_,beta_,L_,Lc_]=h;
```

After that, I would like to make a Manipulate plot such as, for example:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[Re[h1[x, alpha, beta, L, Lc]], {x, 0.1, 1}, 
PlotLegends -> {"h(x)"}], {beta, 0, 1},{alpha, 0, 1},{L, 0, 1},{Lc, 0, 1}]
```

However, it doesnt work. Where are my mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Model your code on the following:

```
Block[{x, a, b}, h[x_, a_, b_] = a Sin[b x]];
Manipulate[
  Plot[h[x, a, b], {x, 0, 10},
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
  {a, -1, 1},
  {b, π/4, 2 π, π/4}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: What is the block function doing? I would like to remind you also that on the rhs of 
    h[x_,a_,b_]
I dont want to right the expression but to state simply 
    h
Is that allowed?

Comment: I am getting $Aborted or an empty Plot. I read somewhere else that this is due to long expressions inside Manipulate. Some sort of bug/crash?

Comment: @AndreaG. `Block`protects the rhs of the definition from being contaminated by global definitions of `x`, `a` and `b`. Sorry but I can't answer the additional questions. The one about `h` being allowed make no sense. The one about your crashes/aborts can't be tested without knowing the expression you are using.